# Getting an NSInternalInconsistencyException Error in iOS 5.0.1

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, ios5, ipad-2

I am getting the error in iOS 5.0.1 but working below the iOS 5.0.1 version.

the crash report is as follows: -

> Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
>
> OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x00000000,
>   0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information:
>
> > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not
> >     locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'PageDetail''

You can see my code,

```
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PageDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil)
    {
        // Handle the error.
        //NSLog(@"mutableFetchResults == nil");
    }
    [self setPagesArray:mutableFetchResults];   
    [request release];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    return [pagesArray count];
}
```

any help here would be appreciated and thanks you in advance.

Comment: As the error points out, there was no Model for `PageDetail` found. Are you sure that there is one?

Answer (score 0):

You should connect class owner view property with actual view you are presenting...